# Не с прилагательными 4

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать в данном случае "не полноподъемные"?

...например, специальные не полноподъемные клапаны для сброса жидкостей...

Answer (score 4):

> Как правильно написать в данном случае "не полноподъемные"?

Как в ГОСТе -- **слитно.**

См.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Корректно слитное написание. Раздельное написание возможно будет, если надо подчеркнуть отрицание. Напр.: Это не полноподъемные клапаны, а...

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Тут спасибом не отделываются - ЛОшку выбирать надо!

Answer (score 0):

Специальные неполноподъемные клапаны для сброса жидкостей.

Думаю, что написание слитное, так как это слово терминологического характера, вряд ли здесь можно использовать отрицание.

Comment: Спасибо большое.